# Tracking the source of PostgreSQL authentication failures in Linux Localhost

Tags: linux, logs, docker, postgresql

I have these logs in my PostgreSQL database log file that appeared after I changed the database password.

```
2023-09-14 11:57:15.937 UTC [3401773] username@db-name FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "username"
2023-09-14 11:57:15.937 UTC [3401773] username@db-name DETAIL:  Password does not match for user "username" 
Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 96: "host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5"
```

How can I track where is the source of this request?
All of my services are running from docker containers and even when I stopped them the same error keeps showing in PostgreSQL logs.

This is the syslog that I think is related to these requests:

```
Sep 14 12:43:23 dev supervisord[539]: 2023-09-14 12:43:23,814 INFO exited: laravel-worker_04 (exit status 1; not expected)
Sep 14 12:43:27 dev supervisord[539]: 2023-09-14 12:43:27,025 INFO spawned: 'laravel-worker_04' with pid 3417768
Sep 14 12:43:28 dev supervisord[539]: 2023-09-14 12:43:28,229 INFO success: laravel-worker_04 entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
```

And, these logs keep repeating even if I restart the system. I want to know how can I find the file that causes these requests even after restarting.
I checked crontab and services and there was no cronjob or service related to this.

### Update

I can find the process ID from PostgreSQL connections. And this is the output of `ps aux pid`:

```
postgres: 12/main: username database 127.0.0.1(s-port) idle
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found that!
The second log that I posted was about `supervisord` service. But I didn't know at that time what is `supervisord`. When I checked the `supervisord` processes I found that it was a process named `laravel-worker` that was running a queued job in the background.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to find from where a command is executed

in general the simple answer is **yes** and it will be in `/var/log/audit/audit.log` as a result of the **auditd** subsystem in linux.  But you will have to tailor the `/etc/audit/rules.d/audit.rules` file to capture such a thing.  I don't believe every command is captured by default... that would blow up the audit.log after an hour.

In your case you would put a watch `-w` on a folder location to capture such a command being run, or call it out that command specifically as a rule, and then in `audit.log` search on that command.  There will be an `exe=` field on an audit line showing that command being run, and then either on that line or subesquent lines a `cwd=` current working directory of *where that command was executed from.*

Here are some sample `/etc/audit/rules.d/audit.rules`

```
-a always,exit -F path=/usr/sbin/semanage -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-priv_change
-a always,exit -F path=/usr/sbin/setsebool -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-priv_change
-a always,exit -F path=/usr/bin/chcon -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-priv_change
-a always,exit -F path=/usr/sbin/setfiles -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-priv_change
-a always,exit -F path=/usr/bin/passwd -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-passwd
-a always,exit -F path=/usr/sbin/unix_chkpwd -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-passwd
-a always,exit -F path=/usr/bin/gpasswd -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-passwd
-a always,exit -F path=/usr/bin/chage -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-passwd
-a always,exit -F path=/usr/sbin/userhelper -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-passwd
-a always,exit -F path=/usr/bin/su -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-priv_change
-a always,exit -F path=/usr/bin/sudo -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-priv_change

-w /var/run/faillock -p wa -k logins
-w /var/log/lastlog -p wa -k logins
-w /etc/sudoers -p wa -k privileged-actions
-w /etc/sudoers.d/ -p wa -k privileged-actions
```

**Complete /etc/audit/rules.d/audit.rules file you can use**

Make the below the entire `/etc/audit/rules.d/audit.rules` text file; back up your existing one to `audit.rules.orig`.  Then do a `service auditd restart` followed by a `service auditd status -l` to see if you had any syntax errors the status should respond with *active (running)* and basic info nothing error like.

```
## First rule - delete all
-D

## Increase the buffers to survive stress events.
## Make this bigger for busy systems
# -b 8192

# set from 8k to 1mb
-b 1048576


# 2 is shutdown, 1 is runlevel 1
-f 1


-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S execve -C uid!=euid -F euid=0 -k setuid
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S execve -C uid!=euid -F euid=0 -k setuid
-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S execve -C gid!=egid -F egid=0 -k setgid
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S execve -C gid!=egid -F egid=0 -k setgid

-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S chown -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k perm_mod
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S chown -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k perm_mod

-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S chmod -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k perm_mod
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S chmod -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k perm_mod


-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S setxattr -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k perm_mod
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S setxattr -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k perm_mod

-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S open -F exit=-EPERM -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k access
-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S open -F exit=-EACCES -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k access
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S open -F exit=-EPERM -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k access
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S open -F exit=-EACCES -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k access

-a always,exit -F path=/usr/sbin/semanage -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-priv_change
-a always,exit -F path=/usr/sbin/setsebool -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-priv_change
-a always,exit -F path=/usr/bin/chcon -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-priv_change
-a always,exit -F path=/usr/sbin/setfiles -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-priv_change

-w /var/run/faillock -p wa -k logins
-w /var/log/lastlog -p wa -k logins

-a always,exit -F path=/usr/bin/passwd -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-passwd
-a always,exit -F path=/usr/sbin/unix_chkpwd -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-passwd
-a always,exit -F path=/usr/bin/gpasswd -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-passwd
-a always,exit -F path=/usr/bin/chage -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-passwd
-a always,exit -F path=/usr/sbin/userhelper -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-passwd
-a always,exit -F path=/usr/bin/su -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-priv_change
-a always,exit -F path=/usr/bin/sudo -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-priv_change

-w /etc/sudoers -p wa -k privileged-actions
-w /etc/sudoers.d/ -p wa -k privileged-actions

-a always,exit -F path=/usr/bin/newgrp -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-priv_change
-a always,exit -F path=/usr/bin/chsh -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-priv_change

-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S mount -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-mount
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S mount -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-mount
-a always,exit -F path=/usr/bin/mount -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-mount

-a always,exit -F path=/usr/bin/umount -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-mount
-a always,exit -F path=/usr/sbin/postdrop -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-postfix
-a always,exit -F path=/usr/sbin/postqueue -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-postfix
-a always,exit -F path=/usr/libexec/openssh/ssh-keysign -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-ssh
-a always,exit -F path=/usr/bin/crontab -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-cron
-a always,exit -F path=/usr/sbin/pam_timestamp_check -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k privileged-pam
-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S create_module -k module-change
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S create_module -k module-change
-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S init_module -k module-change
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S init_module -k module-change


-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S delete_module -k module-change
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S delete_module -k module-change

-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -S unlink -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k delete
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -S unlink -F auid>=1000 -F auid!=unset -k delete

-w /usr/bin/kmod -p x -F auid!=unset -k module-change
-w /etc/passwd -p wa -k identity
-w /etc/group -p wa -k identity
-w /etc/gshadow -p wa -k identity
-w /etc/shadow -p wa -k identity
-w /etc/security/opasswd -p wa -k identity
```

Comment: Sorry I'm not a pro. How can I find the folder location that you said? I don't even know the real command that causes these logs.

Comment: by using an audit rule having `-k whatever`, where my example above has `logins` and `privileged-actions` you would do something unique like a `-k ABCXYZ` then search for `ABCXYZ` within `/var/log/audit/audit.log` to try and find what you are looking for.  I will post a complete `/etc/audit/rules.d/audit.rules` file which you can add one `-w` type entry that would be related to your PostGreSQL which would hopefully capture what you're looking for.... *your throwing darts at a wall but at least you're facing the generally correct direction.*

Comment: I copied all your rules but I don't have any log in the audit log file related to the postgres user. I do get some logs about user logins but not related to the PostgreSQL logs that I said in the question.

Comment: I updated the question with the ps aux output.

Answer (score 0):

If you add %h to your [Postgresql log config](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-LINE-PREFIX) you'll get the IP address in those logs. I think this can't be done without a restart of the DBMS. Alternatively you could log new connections from iptables and reconcile the log data. Assuming a policy of accept and no existing rules....

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -j LOG --log-prefix ' INBOUND TCP ' --log-level 4
```

Comment: I added the log entry that shows the connection is coming from 127.0.0.1/32 which means it is an internal process I think.

Comment: Then use auditd to track back to the executable + user if you don't have logs from a client showing a failed connection.